# How to speed up adding a primary key in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, primary-key

Right now adding a primary key to a table takes 2ish hours to finish.

```
ALTER TABLE <table-name> ADD PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c,d,e);

a: VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci',
b: SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
c: YEAR SMALLINT(4) NOT NULL,
d: INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
e: INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

The number of permutations in each column in this specific table as following:

a: 12 permutations
b: 83 permutations
c:  6 permutations
d: 200 permutations
e: 200 permutations

Right now I plan to change column a from VARCHAR(50) into INT.  I wonder if there is any other trick to speed up the query?  Thanks.

Some more information:

```
MySQL 5.6
50 million rows
Using InnoDB
Didn't tune any Innodb settings. All default Amazon AWS Aurora settings. 
SSD

There is another index on 
    d: INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    e: INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

Two other indexes on other columns f & g, which are not included in the primary key.  Thanks.
```

Comment: Spinny disk or SSD? How many rows? How many other indicies? Have you tuned your InnoDB engine, or are you even using InnoDB? There's way too many variables here.

Comment: hi @tadman; thanks.  Just answer your questions in the edited post.  Thank you.

Comment: The storage component is really important here. An HDD will be orders of magnitude slower than SSD. I just did a migration like this that was going to take a week on a regular HDD but took only six hours on an SSD.

Comment: thanks @tadman.  Just confirm that the query is run on SSD.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a primary key in InnoDB requires copying the entire table and rebuilding secondary indexes. There's no way to avoid that.

Aurora has poor write performance for secondary indexes. So you could try dropping your secondary indexes temporarily before you add the primary key.

Amazon Aurora has changed a lot of internals of InnoDB, and they have not published information needed for precise tuning choices. Aurora uses a proprietary storage technology, and there isn't much information available for tuning this. So you could try contacting Amazon for some consulting help.